# jQuery hide and show toggle div with plus and minus icon

Tags: jquery, html, css, hide, show

I have the code working for the show and hide the `div`. How would I add two different icons as a sprite image for when the show and hide are active?

For example: **+** icon for show me, then a **-** icon for hide me.

Here is the code, I have: 
http://jsfiddle.net/BLkpG/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".slidingDiv").hide();
   $(".show_hide").show();

    $('.show_hide').click(function(){
    $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
  });
});
```

Need to change image to the above when toggled to a **+** or **-**.

Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try something like this

**jQuery**

```
$('#toggle_icon').toggle(function() {

    $('#toggle_icon').text('-');
    $('#toggle_text').slideToggle();

}, function() {

    $('#toggle_icon').text('+');
    $('#toggle_text').slideToggle();

});
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" id="toggle_icon">+</a>

<div id="toggle_text" style="display: none">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s
</div>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pfknd9ra/)**

Comment: Downvoted because I honestly don't think this is the best answer. It is way too long and not efficient at all.

Comment: I am sorry that you have to go on a revenge rampage, it's a bit sad. I was only trying to help the topic starter because I thought your answer was unrightfully accepted. And then you start downvoting some random answers of mine only to have some sort of virtual revenge? Poor you. :)

Comment: I explained why I downvoted your post. This is a Q&A-site, which means we are looking for the **BEST** answer. By downvoting, I show TS that your answer is not as good as it could be. When he unaccepts it or when you change your code, I might remove the downvote. Unlike you, who is childlishly downvoting all my posts without even telling why. And you are supposed to be 27 years old ...

Comment: Good. Well, optimise your code and I'll remove my downvote. That's the whole point of StackExchange, right? **Getting the best answer for our users?** Well then don't take downvotes personally. It's to improve our quality.

Comment: I don't think that a plugin should be used for this simple functionality. The answers of @Vytautas Butkus and Roko C. Buljan and Bram Vanroy show that this can easily be achieved with less code and without plugin.

Answer (score 10):

I would say the most elegant way is this:

```
<div class="toggle"></div>
<div class="content">...</div>
```

then css:

```
.toggle{
 display:inline-block;
height:48px;
width:48px;  background:url("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/pixelmixer/basic/48/plus-icon.png");
}
.toggle.expanded{
  background:url("http://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/onebit/PNG/onebit_32.png");
}
```

and js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var $content = $(".content").hide();
  $(".toggle").on("click", function(e){
    $(this).toggleClass("expanded");
    $content.slideToggle();
  });
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/z7F75/1/)

Comment: I think this is pretty cool, I've tried implementing something similar by going off of this but hasn't worked out for me yet :p https://jsfiddle.net/a4tas9qu/4/ is what I tried if you can see what I'm missing and let me know that'd be awesome <3

Answer (score 9):

Toggle the text `Show` and `Hide` and move your `backgroundPosition` **Y** axis

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/BLkpG/900/)**

```
$(function(){ // DOM READY shorthand

    $(".slidingDiv").hide();

    $('.show_hide').click(function( e ){
        // e.preventDefault(); // If you use anchors
        var SH = this.SH^=1; // "Simple toggler"
        $(this).text(SH?'Hide':'Show')
               .css({backgroundPosition:'0 '+ (SH?-18:0) +'px'})
               .next(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
    });

});
```

CSS:

```
.show_hide{
  background:url(plusminus.png) no-repeat;
  padding-left:20px;  
}
```

Comment: Good one, just a suggestion, you might like to prevent default as you are using `#` on `a`

Comment: @Mr.Alien oh, I missed that really important detail. good catch. Edited.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a quick edit of Enve's answer. I do like roXor's solution, but background images are not necessary. And everbody seems to forgot a `preventDefault` as well.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".slidingDiv").hide();

  $('.show_hide').click(function(e) {
    $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle("fast");
    var val = $(this).text() == "-" ? "+" : "-";
    $(this).hide().text(val).fadeIn("fast");
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="show_hide">+</a>

<div class="slidingDiv">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta.
    Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. </p>

  <p>Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Curabitur sodales ligula in libero. Sed dignissim lacinia nunc. Curabitur tortor. Pellentesque nibh. Aenean quam. In scelerisque sem at dolor. Maecenas mattis.
    Sed convallis tristique sem. Proin ut ligula vel nunc egestas porttitor. Morbi lectus risus, iaculis vel, suscipit quis, luctus non, massa. Fusce ac turpis quis ligula lacinia aliquet. Mauris ipsum. </p>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked for me.

Comment: I think it'd be nice to update the answer to select ONLY the slidingDiv class following the +/- click.   `$(this).next('.slidingDiv')`

Answer (score 2):

this works:

http://jsfiddle.net/UhEut/

CSS:

```
.show_hide {
    display:none;
}
.plus:after {
    content:" +";
}
.minus:after {
    content:" -";
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".slidingDiv").hide();
  $(".show_hide").addClass("plus").show();
  $('.show_hide').toggle(
      function(){
          $(".slidingDiv").slideDown();
          $(this).addClass("minus");
          $(this).removeClass("plus");
      },
      function(){
          $(".slidingDiv").slideUp();
          $(this).addClass("plus");
          $(this).removeClass("minus");
      }
  );
});
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="show_hide">Show/hide</a>

<div class="slidingDiv" style="display: block;">
Check out the updated jQuery plugin for doing this: <a href="http://papermashup.com/jquery-show-hide-plugin/" class="show_hide" target="_blank" style="display: inline;">jQuery Show / Hide Plugin</a>
</div>
```

in the CSS, instead of `content:" +";` You can put an `background-image` (with `background-position:right center;` and `background-repeat:no-repeat` and maybe making the `.show_hide` displayed as block and give him a width, so that the bg-image is not overlayed by the link-text itself).

Comment: is it possible to get the + icon visible before its clicked also? Thanks for the above, 99% there. cheers

Comment: i edited my post already with this line: `$(".show_hide").addClass("plus").show();` (3rd in jQuery) --> `.addClass("plus")`. ;-)

Comment: You can cut this down very easily with `slideToggle`, `toggleClass` and a shorthand if-function.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how to do it with an arrow instead of a `+` and `-`. This uses `jQuery` to change classes on the element, and `CSS` to style the arrow.

```js
$(".toggleHide").click(function() {
  $(".elementToHide").slideToggle("fast");
  $(this).find("i").toggleClass("down up");
});
```

```css
i {
  border: solid black;
  border-width: 0 5px 5px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
  /* Safari */
  transition-duration: 1s;
}

.up {
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
}

.down {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h3 class="toggleHide"><i class="down"></i></h3>
<aside class="elementToHide">
  Content to hide
</aside>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div class="Settings" id="GTSettings">
  <h3 class="SettingsTitle"><a class="toggle" ><img src="${appThemePath}/images/toggle-collapse-light.gif" alt="" /></a>General Theme Settings</h3>
  <div class="options">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <h4>Back-Ground Color</h4>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="body-backGroundColor" class="themeselector" readonly="readonly">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <h4>Text Color</h4>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="body-fontColor" class="themeselector" readonly="readonly">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="Settings" id="GTSettings">
  <h3 class="SettingsTitle"><a class="toggle" ><img src="${appThemePath}/images/toggle-collapse-light.gif" alt="" /></a>Content Theme Settings</h3>
  <div class="options">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <h4>Back-Ground Color</h4>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="body-backGroundColor" class="themeselector" readonly="readonly">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <h4>Text Color</h4>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="body-fontColor" class="themeselector" readonly="readonly">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".options").hide();
  $(".SettingsTitle").click(function(e) {
    var appThemePath = $("#appThemePath").text();

    var closeMenuImg = appThemePath + '/images/toggle-collapse-light.gif';
    var openMenuImg = appThemePath + '/images/toggle-collapse-dark.gif';

    var elem = $(this).next('.options');
    $('.options').not(elem).hide('fast');
    $('.SettingsTitle').not($(this)).parent().children("h3").children("a.toggle").children("img").attr('src', closeMenuImg);
    elem.toggle('fast');
    var targetImg = $(this).parent().children("h3").children("a.toggle").children("img").attr('src') === closeMenuImg ? openMenuImg : closeMenuImg;
    $(this).parent().children("h3").children("a.toggle").children("img").attr('src', targetImg);
  });

});
```