# Toggle multiple divs using images

Tags: jquery, image, toggle

I like Vytautas Butkus' solution to this question (second answer down at [jQuery hide and show toggle div with plus and minus icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14186565/jquery-hide-and-show-toggle-div-with-plus-and-minus-icon) and a demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/z7F75/41/)):

```
  $(".toggle").on("click", function(e){
    $(this).toggleClass("expanded");
    $content.slideToggle();
  });
```

But if there are multiple divs per page, this code toggles them all at the same time. Other solutions get near to what I'm looking for, but I like that this code uses images, changes the images on toggle, and doesn't use anchor tags. How can this code be modified to function the same but open only the div that's being clicked? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `next()` if your div with class toggle  and div with class content are next to each other respectively...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var $content = $(".content").hide();
  $(".toggle").on("click", function (e) {
    $(this).toggleClass("expanded");
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
  });
});
```

[working fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/z7F75/47/)

Comment: Oh, yeah, that's what I was looking for! Thanks so much. Now, at the risk of sounding ungrateful...is there a way to place the div with class toggle AFTER the div with class content? I just like the toggle image to sit at the bottom of the expanded div. I tried that order in the html and then used 'previous' (just a guess) instead of 'next' but that didn't work.

Comment: yes .. that should work.. :)... use `prev()` instead of next().. anyways welcome... glad it helped... happy coding.. let me know if you having problem with the prev() :)..here you go.. fiddle for prev http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/z7F75/49/

Comment: Ah, 'prev' not 'previous'. Got it! That works perfectly. I want you to take the rest of the day off. With pay.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $(".slidingDiv").hide();
   $(".show_hide").show();

   $('.show_hide').toggle(function(){
       var that = $(this);
       $(this).next(".slidingDiv").slideDown(
         function(){
          that.text("-")
         }
       );
   },function(){
       var that = $(this);
       $(this).next(".slidingDiv").slideUp(
       function(){
          that.text("+")
       }
       );
   });
});
```