# Jquery to Show/Hide Multiple Divs (by ID) with Icon Toggle

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get some jQuery to work and I know (well, think) that I'm close to the solution based on the information I found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14186565/jquery-hide-and-show-toggle-div-with-plus-and-minus-icon).

Essentially what I want is to have multiple plus/minus icons on a page that when clicked toggle the icon and show a specific DIV based on an ID value.

Looking at this example below, the content in the DIV would be hidden until the icon was clicked. Once clicked the plus icon changes to a minus icon. If the minus icon were clicked, the content would be hidden again. Multiple DIV's should be allowed to be shown at the same time, so it's almost like each toggle should be independent.

[... if there could be a 'show/hide all' link that would be awesome!]

```
<div><a href="#" id="content1">[Plus Icon]</a> Content Title</div>
<div id="content1">This is some content. Really exciting content!</div>

<div><a href="#" id="content2">[Plus Icon]</a> Different Content</div>
<div id="content2">Here is more content. This content is less exciting.</div>
```

Note: In my above example, the div that display are right below the link, but that is not always the case. Sometimes the toggle link is in a different spot.

As you can see, I want to be able to specify an ID in the toggle link that corrosponds to the DIV to be displayed hidden.

And, if the showing/hiding could be animated with a  sliding effect, that would be good.

The two scripts I have from the other question I found do almost what I want, except they only relate to one DIV and don't have the ID type system I'm describing.

Script Credit to: Vytautas Butkus

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z7F75/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){


  $(".slidingDiv").hide();

    $('.show_hide').click(function(){
        $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
      var isShow = $(this).text() == 'Show';
      $(this).text(isShow ? 'Hide' : 'Show').css({backgroundPosition:'0 '+ (isShow?-18:0) +'px'});
    });

});

.show_hide{
  background:url(http://img37.imageshack.us/img37/1127/plusminus.png) no-repeat;
  padding-left:20px;  
}

<a href="#" class="show_hide">Show</a>

<div class="slidingDiv" style="display: block;">
Check out
</div>
```

Script Credit to: roXon

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BLkpG/7/)

Note: His script toggles the text as well, which I don't really want.

```
$(document).ready(function(){


  $(".slidingDiv").hide();

    $('.show_hide').click(function(){
        $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
      var isShow = $(this).text() == 'Show';
      $(this).text(isShow ? 'Hide' : 'Show').css({backgroundPosition:'0 '+ (isShow?-18:0) +'px'});
    });

});

.show_hide{
  background:url(http://img37.imageshack.us/img37/1127/plusminus.png) no-repeat;
  padding-left:20px;  
}

<a href="#" class="show_hide">Show</a>

<div class="slidingDiv" style="display: block;">
Check out
</div>
```

Many thanks in advance for your help! As always, it is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, what you're looking for is a way to specify the specific div to show/hide for a given button.  The implementation for this can differ depending on how you are building the divs to be shown and hidden, but here is one possible solution.

On the show/hide button, add an attribute.  Doesn't matter what it is, I might call it `targetElement` or something.  So you would end up with `<a targetElement="content1" href="#" id="content1">[Plus Icon]</a>`.

Then when attaching the click event handler to this element, pass in the event.  So something like this - `('.show_hide').click(function(event){`.  Then, inside the handler function, you can get the name of the target div like this - `var target_id = $(event.target).attr("targetElement")`, and then show/hide it directly, like this  - `#(("#" + target_id)).show();`

Again, how exactly you go about this can differ based on your exact setup and implementation - this is a very specific question - but hopefully this solution will work, or at least point you in the right direction by providing an example of passing data into an event handler.

Comment: Hi Scott... first off, thanks for the super fast reply! I do think you're understanding me correctly. I basically want a plus/minus icon that can be toggled to show/hide a specific DIV on the page indicated by an ID value. Please forgive my ignorance (or newbie-ness), but I don't totally understand what you are suggesting. Would it be possible to create a "fiddle" example so I can see it in action and then figure out if this is exactly what I need (...I think it might be). Thanks!

Comment: Just to further clarify (because I appreciate your time and don't want to waste it!)... the goal is to say "click icon with ID of 1" then "show div with the ID of 1". And, while showing that div, toggle the state of the icon so it changes from a plus to a minus. Then, when the minus is clicked, hide that div. Thanks again!

Comment: Here is a jsFiddle where the `div` that you're clicking is essentially "tied" to the `div` that it toggles by the `targetElement` attribute. http://jsfiddle.net/sDjE8/

Answer (score 0):

I would like to say this in a comment but i dont got the rep for it yet.

I see that you have 2 times the same id. This will create a conflict in javascript:

```
<a href="#" id="content1">
<div id="content1">

<a href="#" id="content2">
<div id="content2">
```

Comment: Hi Jim.. thanks for the comment. I was just trying to indicate that clicking the link for "content 1" would open the div for "content 1". It's totally OK if they have different IDs... I was just trying to explain things in a way that I thought made sense... although maybe I just made it more complex. My bad!