# folding sections denoted by headers in rmarkdown

Tags: r-markdown

I have been unsuccessful at getting Rmarkdown to fold sections denoted by a #section_header. I know code folding is great, but my goal is to be able to compare results across a number of different analytic pipelines without having to scroll all over the place to find what I am looking for. If I could fold each iteration of my analyses neatly into a foldable section, then I would be able to easily compare any two pipelines, while ignoring the rest. I've seen a bit posted about how to implement this in a pdf output but does anyone know how to implement something like this in an html output?

Thanks in advance.
-N

Answer (score 0):

You want to slide whole sections, not just code -- otherwise an [HTML notebook](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/r_notebooks.html) would probably do it.

So take a look at this Gist, where I cobbled something together using a little bit of jQuery, probably from [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14186565/jquery-hide-and-show-toggle-div-with-plus-and-minus-icon#14186647):

```html
<script src="https://gist.github.com/flynn-d/b756e512f5be7f553aad007f0ac37220.js"></script>
```

[Link to Gist](https://gist.github.com/flynn-d/b756e512f5be7f553aad007f0ac37220)